How Can I Customize the Categories and Items in the Windows 10 File Explorer Navigation Pane?
I'm looking to modify the "Navigation Pane" in Windows 10's File Explorer to better suit my workflow. I've attached a screenshot of the current state of my Navigation Pane. I want to add new categories and items and remove some existing ones, but I'm unsure how to proceed.
So far, I've tried navigating to the "View" tab, then "Options", and subsequently the "View" tab within the options menu. I looked under the "Navigation pane" section but couldn't find any settings to control the content and organization of the pane directly.
Can someone guide me on how to customize the categories and items within the Navigation Pane? Can I use any built-in settings, third-party tools, or registry edits to achieve this?

               


Besides looking for settings, what else have you tried and what research have you done?

@music2myear I have searched the internet as much as I could. I have found the Winaero Tweaker from here, which I prefer not to use freemium software, which I don't know. There are some suggestions for registry modification here, which I haven't been able to comprehend so far. Have you found a way to do this?

Windows Explorer Navigation pane is not very customizable. The right information pane is -- for example, additional columns can display tags, frame rate, etc.
